# How to generate swagger doc automatically in ktor ,or how you write api doc in ktor

Tags: kotlin, swagger, ktor, api-doc

Api doc needed for our backend project. I want to generate api doc automatically like what we can do in spring_swagger. So how can we do the same thing in ktor?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such functionality in Ktor.

Comment: I am not sure it is even possible to do. In Spring it's easy because all you need to do is look for annotations on classes and methods. In ktor, there are no such annotations. I currently have no idea how a swagger generator would be able to find out the structure of a POST request payload